# Is it possible to utilize the "light" property of hand crossbows without crossbow feats?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons

I am making a bard and noticed they have proficiency in hand crossbows. Upon looking at hand crossbows, they have the light property, which apparently means they can be used in the off-hand without penalties.
But is there even a way to make use of the crossbow in my off-hand? If I wanted to use them with another weapon in the main-hand and without the feat, then the loading property would get in the way. (Apparently, crossbows are being loaded just before they fire.)

What if I had my main hand free to cast spells (unless I'd need to be holding the instrument, I guess?), couldn't I then technically cast a spell with my hand and then fire the crossbow? Or how about Vicious Mockery -- it uses only a verbal component and it's not an attack spell either. Should I be able to use VM and then fire the hand crossbow from my off-hand as a bonus action?

Comment: Something that wasn't really made clear in the duplicate, but asked here (might even make it worth reopening). You can only make an "off-hand" attack when you use the Attack action. Spells like "Vicious Mockery" use the Cast a Spell action and do not qualify for using your Bonus Action for an off-hand attack.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MivaScott. I'm not quite sure why this is marked as duplicate, I'd already found and read the original thread and couldn't find a satisfying answer.

I believe the off-hand attack you're referring to is the one from the feat's description though, isn't it? Basically I can't find anywhere that says you can't use the crossbow as a bonus action regardless of your main action, like you would use a spell or other ability as a bonus action...

Comment: For the most part, in D&D, you can only do what the game says you can do.  You cannot make a bonus action attack with a hand crossbow unless the game says you can.  The feat says you can make that bonus action attack _IF_ you use the Attack action.  Not the Cast a Spell action, or similar.  I hope that clears that up?

Comment: You can only make an attack with a Bonus Action (known as an "off-hand" attack from previous version) if fighting with [two weapons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/combat#TwoWeaponFighting). But both weapons must be melee attacks. No crossbows. The [Crossbow Expert](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/customization-options#CrossbowExpert) feat gets around the melee portion, but ONLY for the hand crossbow. So your spell casting is still out of luck.

Comment: Your question asks: "Is it possible to utilize the "light" property of hand crossbows without crossbow feats?", the linked question has answers stating that there is *no* way to utilize the light property of hand crossbows, with or without feats